# Is it possible to, Click to zoom in and switch to vector layer beneath, on webpage to show GeoServer WMS layers via OpenLayers?

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers, wms, web-mapping

I have 2 vector layers in GeoServer

First is a district layer
[image: District]

Second is a state layer

[image: State]

When I make a Layer group of these layers in the GeoServer and showing that layer group on the web-page, using open layers “get-feature information” function, that shows attributes of both layers on the web-page, but I only want to restrict these features to the district layer only (I don't want to see the state layer features).

Is it possible to click over to select some state and zoom in to the district layer below, and the state layer doesn't show after that,
and when I  zoom out again, the state layer re-appears?

[image: layer group on web-page]

```
window.onload = init;

function init(){

    //Geoserver layer 
    // wmsSource = indialayersource

    var indialayersource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/agrodss/wms",
        params: {"LAYERS":"agrodss:Rainfall", "tiled": true},
        serverType: "geoserver"
    })

    // wmsLayer = indialayer

    var indialayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: indialayersource, 
        visible:true,
        title: "ForAgrodss"
    })

        // hover

    var highlightStyle = new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)',
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#3399CC',
        width: 3,
      }),
    });



  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: function(extent) {
      return 'localhost:8080/geoserver/agrodss/ows?service=wfs&' + 
             'version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&' +
             'typeName=agrodss:india_boundary_updated_GCS&maxFeatures=500&' + 
             'outputFormat=application%2Fjson' +
             'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
    });
    
    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
       source: vectorSource
    });
    // map.addLayer(vector);

    // view = myview

    var myview = new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([80, 22]),
            zoom: 4.5, 
            maxZoom: 8,
            minZoom: 4,
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [vector, indialayer],
        target: 'js-map',
        view: myview,
      });

      var selected = null;
      var status = document.getElementById('status');

      map.on('pointermove', function (e) {
        if (selected !== null) {
          selected.setStyle(undefined);
          selected = null;
        }
      
        map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function (f) {
          selected = f;
          f.setStyle(highlightStyle);
          return true;
        });
      
        if (selected) {
          status.innerHTML = '&nbsp;Hovering: ' + selected.get('name');
        } else {
          status.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
        }
      });
      

      map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
        var myviewResolution = myview.getResolution();
        var url = indialayersource.getFeatureInfoUrl(
          evt.coordinate,
          myviewResolution,
          'EPSG:3857',
          {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html', 'FEATURE_COUNT': '5'}
        );
        if (url) {
          fetch(url)
            .then(function (response) { return response.text(); })
            .then(function (html) {
              document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = html;
            });
        }
      });
    
      map.on('pointermove', function (evt) {
        if (evt.dragging) {
          return;
        }
        var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
        var hit = map.forEachLayerAtPixel(pixel, function () {
          return true;
        });
        map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
      });



    map.on('click', function(e){
        console.log(e.coordinate);


    })
}
```

I am trying to use [Select Features by Hover of OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-hover-features.html) to select the state, then go to district layer.
But it ain't working.

Comment: Is it necessary for you to have both layers on your map and control them by zoom level or it's just for having control on displaying labels in specific zoom levels?

Comment: It’s an approach, to click on the layer to move to another with more specific details, but if there is an alternate, I would prefer that over it.

Comment: What you are trying to do requires vector layer for districts, which in your case would be WFS layer, or some plain GeoJSON data, like in the OL example you are citing. For example, here https://github.com/geohacker/india/blob/master/district/india_district.geojson you can get GeoJSON for India districts, but it has hefty 32 MB.

Comment: @TomazicM , both of the layers that I have shown are the layers in GeoServer already, and both of them are vector layer, I didn’t got your point. Should I use the GeoJson vector layer from some local directory ? & I am not sure how to fetch the layer from GeoServer as GeoJson.

Comment: At the moment your are using WMS raster layer from Geoserver. I don't know much about Geoserver, but as far I know, it can also produce WFS layers, which are vector layers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @TomazicM, I did not knew about the WFS layer too, but I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your layers separately and then apply the hover to just the district layer.

Comment: i am getting this CORS error while loading vector layer as WFS, although i have already enabled CORS in my web.xml,  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382938/how-to-enable-cors-while-reading-loading-the-geoserver-layer-as-wfs-layers-in-op